# /proc/partitions major and minor numbers to detect physical disk and partitions

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, procfs, sysfs

```
$ cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1   99998720 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        3  103561216 sda3
   8        4  291514368 sda4
   8        5    1998848 sda5
   8       16   31506432 sdb
   8       17   31505439 sdb1
```

I want to differentiate between physical disks (`/dev/sda`) and logical disks (`/dev/sda1`) from `/proc/partitions` output.

1. One easy way I see is to check with some regex pattern whether it ends with integer or not
2. As I see the output on my machine `sda` has least minor value than all `sdaN` entries
3. check for existence of `/sys/block/[NAME]` So I'll try to read `/sys/block/sdaN` directories (which will fail) and `/sys/block/sda` (which will succeed)

I don't know which one is reliable and Is there any other ways ?

Also how can I reliably make a tree structure like `sda : {sda1, sda2, sda3, sda4, sda4}, sdb : {sdb1}`

1. just by its name
2. by minor numbers
3. again look into `/sys/block`
4. by position (Is it confirmed that sda1 will always come after sda ? e.g. would a logical partition entry always come after the physical disk entry ?)

Comment: You do know that all the partitions for a particular block device should be subdirectories below the parent directory?

Comment: Try the command `lsblk`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't differentiate well between the primary and secondary partitions:

Partitions generally can be of type primary (maximum four), extended (maximum one) or logical (contained within the extended partition). Each partition has a type field that contains a code. This determines the computers operating system or the partitions file system.

```
Primary (max 4)        1-4, 
Extended (max 1)       1-4, 
Logical                5-
```

When it comes to the partitions naming, you usually see that hard disk devices are named /dev/hdx or /dev/sdx with x depending on the hardware configuration.

The partition number, starting the count at 1. Hence the four (possible) primary partitions are numbered 1 to 4. Logical partition counting always starts at 5. Thus /dev/hda2 is the second partition on the first ATA hard disk device, and /dev/hdb5 is the first logical partition on the second ATA hard disk device. Same for SCSI, /dev/sdb3 is the third partition on the second SCSI disk.

For you to create new partitions on disks, `fdisk` shall always be your friend and you just add the space starting from the last taken block, where you can always check them either through `fdisk -l`, or `cat /proc/partitions`

If you can't create devices using `fdisk` or `parted` tools, just mentioned it?!